# SQL SELECT FOR SALES WITH 'COUNT' FROM ANOTHER TABLE

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables. The first one is for sales (name's table is 'ventas') and the other one, for detailed articles by sale (the name is 'ventaArticulos'). Basically, the last one contains all the articles that were sold.

Those are related by the columns ventas.id_venta and ventaArticulos.id_ventaArticulo

[image: schema]

Basically, the idea is to make an SQL SELECT for the first table (ventas) for example, getting the columns 'fecha' and 'importe' but also, perform a 'count' with the total of registers that are in the second table related by sale. (ventas.id_venta and ventaArticulos.id_ventaArticulo)

hope to be clear enough and can help me!

SQL to try to clarify (Obviously it doesn't work):

```
SELECT ventas.fecha, ventas.importe, count(ventaArticulos.id_codigoArt)
FROM ventas JOIN
     ventaArticulos
     ON ventaArticulos.id_ventaArticulo = ventas.id_venta
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Is there any possibility you can provide a query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use table *alise* that could be easier to follow & you forgot to include `GROUP BY` Clause

```
SELECT v.fecha, v.importe, count(va.id_codigoArt) counts
FROM ventas v -- Use alise v entire the query instead of table_name
INNER JOIN ventaArticulos va ON va.id_ventaArticulo = v.id_venta
GROUP BY v.fecha, v.importe;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT v1.fecha, v1.importe, count(v2.id_codigoArt)
FROM ventas v1 , ventaArticulos v2 
where v1.id_ventaArticulo= v2.id_venta
group by v1.fecha, v1.importe 
having count(*) > 1
```